# Transparent NSWindow with visible controls

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

How to make an `NSWindow` transparent while keeping all controls (views, buttons, ...) within this window visible?

Answer (score 3):

```
@implementation MyCustomWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super
            initWithContentRect:contentRect
            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
            backing:bufferingType
            defer:flag];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I had some trouble with these settings. I would set everything up and the window would still show as black. I added setOpacity to 0.9 and that fixed it for me. I'm not sure if it was a bug in my file but hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Remove it's title bar and border, and make a custom content view where you override the drawRect: method and do nothing.